# How to write a makefile with target "errors"?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, gnu

I need to add the target `errors:` to my current makefile so that several different programs are all compiled with the compiler printing **all** possible occuring error messages, such as for example:

```
 error: expected ';' before
```

In my current makefile, I already have the gcc flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra` set (for targets `all`, `debug`) - would this suffice in order to generate a complete output of error messages?

Or is there a need to set target `errors` in a more specific way?

edit: here is part of my current `Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra

SRC = test.c // here I want to add more programs, how is this possible?
BIN = test

binary: $(SRC)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(SRC) $(LDFLAGS)

all: binary
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please edit your question to show much more of your `Makefile`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think he is asking if he uses -Wall and -Werror with make, will it generate messages for what errors are in his code. And if not, how can he generate those messages on his own by editing the makefile

Comment: But still, the OP (codebat) should improve his question by showing more of the `Makefile`

Comment: Your `Makefile` is  missing some *tab* characters. Tabulations are *important* in `Makefile`-s (replace them with four more spaces in your question)

Comment: It will not be possible, some errors depend on some number, e.g., `-ftemplate-depth=42`.

Comment: @codebat: Why can't you simply run `make -k` ?

Comment: No. `-Wall` and `-Wextra` don't generate any errors. They produce warnings. You get errors if your code is not valid C++, not by enabling warnings. And if your code is not valid C++ you will always get errors, you don't need to use an option to ask the compiler to tell you it's invalid.

Comment: As Jonathan said, errors are always reported. You can also use `-Werror` to turn all warnings into errors, but the topic of warnings is broad and complicated.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know but I was just kinda nudging him in the right direction.

Comment: Hi. Even after your question has been answered, the question need to remain as it was for others who encounter your problem. We have repeatedly rolled back your deletion of the question body. Please, stop deleting the question body and replacing it with "problem solved"

Answer (score 1):

You could add before the first target of your `Makefile`

```
 .PHONY: all clean errors
```

and you would add at the end of your `Makefile`

```
 errors: 
       $(MAKE) -k all
```

You should **read the [documentation of GNU `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)**

BTW, you probably mean the rule:

```
binary: $(BIN)
```

and you should avoid naming your executable `test` (which is a builtin command in many shells, and also the standard `/usr/bin/test`)

Comment: yes it sounds like it could be that simple as just set errors: binary